# Slice an image that is 1 layer in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design

I was given a Photoshop file to use as a basis for creating a website. There are many layers in the Photoshop file, however the footer is 1 layer. It looks as if it was created and merged together.

The footer is a background image with text and logos on top of it. I'm not sure how I can slice this up since it is just one layer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You say slice, but it should be easy to split it into squares. Are you actually trying to separate the logos out, the text, or both?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I need the background image and logos. There is text on the layer, but I can handle the text in the HTML.

Comment: So I need the background and four logos.

Comment: Go pixel by pixel and cut out everything you need.

Comment: I could do that for the logos. What would you recommend? I tried the magic wand tool and they turned out very pixelated. How would you get the background image?

Comment: Why not code this?

Comment: @Matt That's the plan, but I need the images to use and the footer layer has been merged.

Comment: This really doesn't make any sense. You can slice that image any way you want. There's absolutely no reason you'd need layers

Comment: @Scott You need to logos in separate images if you want for example to go responsive.

Comment: oop... I failed to see the darker lines at first..all I saw was a flat grey background. Now I see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if the logos were merged with the background (make sure it's not actually a `Smart Object`, though) your best option is to **redraw the whole thing**.

Any chance you can get a new file with the correct layers? The PSD should be optimized for web, and the designer should know how to prepare the assets. You shouldn't have to manipulate the original file, they should have given you the file ready to 'export'.

If you can't get the file fixed and re-sent, my advice is to re-do the background and google + re-do the logos. Otherwise you'll have to use a large image, which would make it impossible to let the logos wrap when you resize your site.